# How to add image in tkinter gui?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I picked up this code and wanted to mess with it, the main problem i'm having is being unable to add an image to the actual gui at a set location on the 2 dimensional array. I get no actual error but also get no output of the image on the gui. Please help! Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, rows=9, columns=9, size=60, color1="light grey", color2="light grey"):
        '''size is the size of a square, in pixels'''

        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.size = size
        self.color1 = color1
        self.color2 = color2
        self.pieces = {}

        canvas_width = columns * size
        canvas_height = rows * size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0,
                            width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height, background="white")
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=2, pady=2)

        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.refresh)

    def addpiece(self, name, image, row=1, column=1):
        bishop = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Sharjeel Jan\\Desktop\\final shit man\\Pieces\\Bishop.gif')
        self.canvas.create_image(1,1, image=bishop, tags=(name, "Bishop"), anchor= "c")
        self.placepiece(name, row, column)

    def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
        '''Place a piece at the given row/column'''
        self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
        x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)
```

def placepiece(self, name, row, column):
        '''Place a piece at the given row/column'''
        self.pieces[name] = (row, column)
        x0 = (column * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        y0 = (row * self.size) + int(self.size/2)
        self.canvas.coords(name, x0, y0)

```
  def refresh(self, event):
        '''Redraw the board, possibly in response to window being resized'''
        xsize = int((event.width-1) / self.columns)
        ysize = int((event.height-1) / self.rows)
        self.size = min(xsize, ysize)
        self.canvas.delete("square")
        color = self.color2
        for row in range(self.rows):
            color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
            for col in range(self.columns):
                x1 = (col * self.size)
                y1 = (row * self.size)
                x2 = x1 + self.size
                y2 = y1 + self.size
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill=color, tags="square")
                color = self.color1 if color == self.color2 else self.color2
        for name in self.pieces:
            self.placepiece(name, self.pieces[name][0], self.pieces[name][1])
        self.canvas.tag_raise("piece")
        self.canvas.tag_lower("square")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    board = GameBoard(root)
    board.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true", padx=4, pady=4)
  # player1 = tk.PhotoImage(data=imagedata)
  # board.addpiece("player1", player1, 0,0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: i tried self.bishop to counter the garbage collection but got the same result.

Comment: Please format your code better using `{}` button above.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] for the specific question you're asking, as opposed to your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single line that tries to put an image to GUI:

```
self.canvas.create_image(1,1, image=bishop, tags=(name, "Bishop"), anchor= "c")
```

which is under `addpiece`.

The line below saves the image in a reference:

```
bishop = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Sharjeel Jan\\Desktop\\final shit man\\Pieces\\Bishop.gif')
```

which is defined *exclusively* for the scope of `addpiece`, when the method is finished, the image disappears if at all being displayed.

Which effectively *makes* this question a duplicate to [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424091/7032856)

---

In order to prevent that, make the image reference available in the scope where `mainloop` is called.

Either *attach* the reference `bishop` *to* an object, for example `self.canvas`, whose reference is available in the scope of `mainloop`:

```
self.canvas.bishop = tk.PhotoImage(file='C:\\Users\\Sharjeel Jan\\Desktop\\final shit man\\Pieces\\Bishop.gif')
self.canvas.create_image(1,1, image=self.canvas.bishop, tags=(name, "Bishop"), anchor= "c")
```

or simply pass the image reference from the `mainloop` scope is in, and *use* that object reference:

```
self.canvas.create_image(1,1, image=image, tags=(name, "Bishop"), anchor= "c")
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same result, im not really sure what the problem is.